# ¿Cómo saber cuándo termina un número en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo una frase, por ejemplo:

```
buenos123dias325.amigo87s.
```

Quiero separarla por números, la salida seria algo como:

```
[123,325,87]
```

pero no sé cómo verificar cuándo el numero termina.

Comment: sería bueno que indicaras qué has intentado. Recomiendo leer [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer con expresiones regulares de la siguiente manera

```
import re
palabra = "buenos123dias325.amigo87s"
numeros = re.findall(r'\d+', palabra)
print(numeros)
```

Lo que que hace el código es buscar a partir de una expresión regular todas las coincidencias, para ser más exactos le estás diciendo que busque todos los dígitos dentro de la palabra y que los almacene en la variable números.

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a repasar [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y a [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/363712/edit) tu respuesta con comentarios adicionales que la complementen.

Comment: Cierto, modifico mi respuesta